# Taylor series expansion for calculus of variations

Tags: taylor-expansion, calculus-of-variations

$\partial f / \partial u'$ is a functional partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $u'$, where $f = \{ u(x), u'(x) \}$, is it possible to expand the same as a Taylor series? say at point $x_1$ say where $x_2 = x_1 + \delta x$, where $\delta x$ is a small incremental increase from $x_1$

Comment: If the variation $\delta u$ is small, we only need to expand $f(u(x),u'(x))$ to first order of $\delta u$ to derive the Euler-Lagrange equation. In Ito calculus, one needs to expand $f(t,X_t)$ to second order in the noise $X_t$. It's a matter of need.

Comment: thanks ... that means i could expand the same as (∂f / ∂u')|x1+(delta x)^2*1/dx*(∂f / ∂u'|x1)+............

Comment: By the way, it's $\delta u$. The expansion is around a function $u(x)$ and $\delta u(x)$ is the variation from it. The first-order expansion gives where the extremum is (what function $u(x)$ makes $\delta f=0$). The second order tells if it's a local maximum or minimum or neither.